Dependency Injection caching of AutoMapper causes 500 error when mapping two different classes containing the same shared class
We have a C# web service using AutoMapper and Dependency Injection.
One controller contains two different calls, call A and call B.
Both calls have unique dto and resource classes that get mapped from dto to resource when the call is made.
Both dtos contain an attribute with a shared custom collection (AutoMappingSharedCollection).
Resetting the cache via iisreset then calling A and then B causes the following AutoMapper error upon calling B:
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error mapping types.
Source=Cannot evaluate the exception source
StackTrace:
Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

Inner Exception 1:
AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Inner Exception 2:
AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Inner Exception 3:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The mapping configuration used:
public AutoMappingWeb()
{
CreateMap<AutoMappingClassALarge, AutoMappingClassALargeMapped>()
.ForMember(
dest => dest.ClassAMappedList,
opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClassAList));

CreateMap<AutoMappingClassA, AutoMappingClassAMapped>()
.ForMember(
dest => dest.Data,
opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Data));

CreateMap<AutoMappingSharedClass, AutoMappingSharedClassMapped>()
.ForMember(
dest => dest.Name,
opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

CreateMap<AutoMappingClassBLarge, AutoMappingClassBLargeMapped>();

CreateMap<AutoMappingClassB, AutoMappingClassBMapped>();
}

The error does not occur if the injected _mapper within the controller is created locally instead like this:
MapperConfiguration config = new(cfg => cfg.AddProfile());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

Another fix/workaround, the one we are temporarily using, is to not use the AutoMappingSharedCollection within AutoMappingClassB and using a simple List instead.
These two possible workarounds alongside the fact that the error only occurs if A is called first after an IISReset leads us to believe that the error is likely some sort of caching interaction between AutoMapper and Dependency Injection but where exactly the bug comes from is beyond us.
Any input on where this issue comes from and how to avoid it would be very helpful.
I have created a test project using Swagger so anyone who's curious can simply have a look at the specific classes, calls and AutoMapper Profile for themselves. You can find it on github here.
I have also previously tried to create an issue for this topic as it seems like a bug to my colleagues and I and isn't a massive issue for us currently given the List replacement workaround. I was directed to create a thread here instead.

Steps to reproduce:

Perform an IIIReset
Call function A
Call function B

Expected behavior:
Both calls A and B should return the respective objects which are being created and mapped within the AutoMapper.Bugfix.Web.AutoMappingController.
The steps for reproduction of the bug have to be done in specifically that order as calling B first will lead to both calls working fine afterwards. Meaning IISReset -> B -> A -> B and any other similar order works completely fine.

Regarding how to avoid, might consider to do unit testing of all mappings being used

Try upgrading AM.

I've looked up the repo you've linked, and I honestly mean no offense, this is a serious objective option: your code is so convoluted, so distant from any industry good practices that even these few classes are incomprehensible to me. It does not compile, but still I really tried to understand what is going on there, but I failed. The cherry on top is AutoMappingSharedCollection which throws internally and is the absolute abomination of a collection implementation.

You should either slim down your code sample to narrow the problem even further or start fixing issues in your own code base, because there are plenty of these. It is very probable, that by resolving issues and improving the quality of your codebase, the AutoMapper issue you are dealing with now will go away. I strongly suspect it is coming from your own code, given the state of it. I know these may be harsh words, but I think you need to hear it. I hope for you, that you are not dealing with some concrete legacy project, so you can still change it.
